# db_field() in php

Tags: php, mysql

Whats wrong with my db_field. in line 15:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE $loFmUname = '".strtolower($db_field['UserName'])."' AND $myPwd = '".$db_field['UserPwd']."'";
```

Code I have is

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_exist = mysql_select_db("seta", $con);

$myUName = $_POST["username"];
$myPwd = $_POST["pwd"];
$loFmUname = strtolower($myUName);

if($db_exist){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE $loFmUname = '".strtolower($db_field['UserName'])."' AND $myPwd = '".$db_field['UserPwd']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result){
        $_SESSION['loged'] = '$loFmUname';
        header('Location: index.html');
        die();
    } else {
        echo "Invalid username and/or password please";
        echo "<a href='login.php'>try again</a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Sorry Database Not Found";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Could you please post the error messages? It would help a lot in answering your question. Thanks!

Comment: Your code has a lot of errors in it.  You may want to consider revisiting basic PHP and MySQL.  For example, you never define $db_field, and `'$loFmUname'` will be the literal string `$loFmUname`.

Comment: can you make sure you have UserName and UserPwd fields in your database. NOTE These are case-sensitive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE ". $loFmUname." = '".strtolower($db_field['UserName'])."' AND ".$myPwd." = '".$db_field['UserPwd']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: the variable `db_field` is not initialized anywhere with any value. You're not creating it before using it.

Comment: am trying to call it from the database